# JSP Unparseable date exception

Tags: java, date, jsp, jstl

I am having troubles parsing this date: ***Sat Mar 03 14:02:30 GMT 2018***

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat Mar 03 14:02:30 GMT 2018"
```

I am using basic JSP, with core and fmt librarys.

This is my code. I think that patter that I am using is correct (EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy):

```
<c:set var = "now" value = "<%= new java.util.Date()%>" />
<fmt:parseDate value="${now}" var="dateObject" pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" />
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS" value = "${dateObject}" />
```

I have this page working with servlet code and I want change it

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: No JSP expert, the code looks right to me. A locale problem? Saturday isn’t called that in all languages. Less to the point, can you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API with JSP? And are you using `Date.toString` and trying to parse that string back into a `Date`? Could you avoid going forth and back like that? Just asking naively.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `now` is a date (`new java.util.Date()`)... with `fmt:parseDate` you convert a `java.lang.String` representation of date or time to corresponding date or time values. `fmt:formatDate` is the correct function you should be using if you want to present a date object in a specific pattern. 
Try with:

```
<c:set var = "now" value = "<%= new java.util.Date()%>" />
<fmt:formatDate pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" value = "${now}" />
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS" value = "${now}" />
```